# Do we need to lock class member functions if its objects are running in multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, winsock2

I am working with C++ based Networking project using winsock library.
The code is:

```
class NetworkCom
{
private:
    SOCKADDR_IN ClientAddress;
    int ClientAddressSize;
    SOCKET SenderSocket;
public:
    NetworkCom(SOCKET& sock)
    {
        ClientAddressSize = sizeof(ClientAddress);
        getpeername(sock,(SOCKADDR*)&ClientAddress,&ClientAddressSize);

        sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        SenderSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    }

    int SendData(char message[])
    {
        int val;
        val = send(sock,message,sizeof(message),0); // if val <= 0 then error
        return val;     
    }   

    string RecieveData()
    {
        string message;
        char msg[100];

        connect(SenderSocket,(SOCKADDR*)&ClientAddress,&ClientAddressSize);
        recv(SenderSocket,msg,100,0);
        message = msg;

        return message;
    }

    ~NetworkCom()
    {
        cout<<"Closing Connection..";
        closesocket(SenderSocket);
        closesocket(sock);
    }
  };
```

I am going to create a new **NetworkCom** Object for each new client in a new thread.
So when i do so do i need to use mutex to lock the member function of the class evertime a object in a thread is using the member function SendData and RecieveData.

If i have to use mutex....
Is there any way this can be done without mutex

Comment: these two lines do not make sense

`val = send(sock,message,sizeof(message),0); // if val <= 0 then error`

`closesocket(sock);`
 
as you are not storing 'sock'

Comment: `sizeof(message)` is not the size of the array parameter. Use std::string!

Comment: Also, note that spawning a thread per connection, while being a valid approach for many simple applications, [does not scale very well](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) if you need to handle lots of connections at the same time.

Comment: @william jones 
send returns the no. of char sent 
So if val <= 0 so there is a error and thus it serves the purpose of error checking

Answer (score 2):

As most socket APIs, Winsock does not like concurrent access to the same socket:

> `send` should not be called on the same stream-oriented socket
>   concurrently from different threads, because some Winsock providers
>   may split a large send request into multiple transmissions, and this
>   may lead to unintended data interleaving from multiple concurrent send
>   requests on the same stream-oriented socket.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [`recv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx) has similar constraints.

So if you are sharing the same socket between multiple threads, all access to that socket need to be synchronized. A mutex is one way of achieving this synchronisation. If you are using *different* sockets for the different threads though, you do not need to synchronize, as long as you are not sharing any other (mutable) data between threads.